# Is there a way to check that a Linux O.S. has been installed a specific manner?

Tags: linux

I am trying to set a project for public authorities : give a `Raspberry Pi` kind of computer to famillies that cannot afford buying a computer themselves. It would be given with a SD card containing the `Raspbian` O.S. and some useful softwares already installed.

It means that I would have to ask some providers to create for us, let say : 500 SD cards with a script that we would provide : install `Raspbian` version *x.y.z* on it and then do `apt-get install ...`

But there is a security issue. How can I ensure that a provider isn't malevolent and attempt to add any other software we do not want to see on our SD cards ?

Is there a way to check, if I take a SD card randomly and insert it in a `Rasperry Pi`, that the SD card has been created the way I expected, with the good commands ?

Comment: Why is a script needed anyway? Simply make a byte-level writing to SD cards.

Answer (score 2):

There's no way to check how someone has setup an OS on your behalf.  It's always possible to hide things.  If there's a risk of malicious behaviour on the part of the supplier then your only options are to

- work with a more trustworthy supplier
- Make sure you know byte-for-byte the image that should be installed.  This is feasible if you send the supplier the exact image rather than just a script...

You can record the sha256sum (a hash) of every partition on an image and then compare this later with the SD card **before you plug it in and boot it**.  While they could theoretically add an extra partiton, this would be very simple to spot.

The reason you can't work with a hash of the image, is that if an SD card is even one byte larger or smaller than you expect then the hash will be invalid.  Sizes of SD cards do vary even between cards that claim to be a named size.

---

## Steps to record partition hashses

*These steps can be run from any linux machine.  You can use a raspberry pi with a large enough SD  (reccomend at least 16GB)*

1. Download and the image you want to work with.  Eg: the latest [raspbian image](https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspbian/):

   ```
   wget --content-disposition https://downloads.raspberrypi.org/raspbian_full_latest
   unzip *raspbian-stretch-full.zip
   ```

   ```
   ls -lh *raspbian*
   -rw-r--r-- 1 philip philip 5.1G Apr  8 19:43 2019-04-08-raspbian-stretch-full.img
   -rw-r----- 1 philip philip 2.0G Apr  8 19:48 2019-04-08-raspbian-stretch-full.zip
   ```
2. **Customise the image.**
3. Setup loopback device

   ```
   sudo losetup /dev/loop0 2019-04-08-raspbian-stretch-full.img
   sudo partprobe /dev/loop0
   ```

   ```
   ls -lh /dev/loop0*
   brw-rw---- 1 root disk   7, 0 May 15 19:18 /dev/loop0
   brw-rw---- 1 root disk 259, 0 May 15 19:18 /dev/loop0p1
   brw-rw---- 1 root disk 259, 1 May 15 19:18 /dev/loop0p2
   ```
4. Get the sha256sum for each partition (this takes a while!).  Save this to a file.

   ```
   sudo sha256sum /dev/loop0p*
   66aa77d8405ab585865d0e0378f06bd8baa5ab41bbb6e9cc23ac6b2be40974d4  /dev/loop0p1
   1895a2c5d9e93eb3b644d8cacab9d928184290e30bba6d27b7eb9d486c30e5e8  /dev/loop0p2
   ```
5. Cleanup

   ```
   sudo partx -d /dev/loop0
   sudo losetup -d /dev/loop0
   ```

## Checking hashes

Plug the card into any running linux machine.  If you want to use a raspberry pi, you can use a USB SD card reader to plug in the card you want to check as a second card.

The card will appear as a new drive such as `/dev/sda` or `/dev/sdb` ...

Assuming it shows up as `/dev/sda`, you can then get the hash for each partition:

```
ls -lh /dev/sd*
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8, 16 May  9 12:23 /dev/sda
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8, 17 May  9 12:23 /dev/sda1
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8, 18 May  9 12:23 /dev/sda2
```

```
sudo sha256sum /dev/sda1 /dev/sda2
66aa77d8405ab585865d0e0378f06bd8baa5ab41bbb6e9cc23ac6b2be40974d4  /dev/sda1
1895a2c5d9e93eb3b644d8cacab9d928184290e30bba6d27b7eb9d486c30e5e8  /dev/sda2
```

## Customising the image

*These steps can NOT be run from any linux machine, they need an ARM processor like the one on the raspberry pi.*

1. Mount the loop-back partition (`/dev/loop0p2`) created earlier.  The OS is installed on `p2` the boot configuration is on `p1`.

   ```
   mkdir rpi-os
   sudo mount /dev/loop0p2 rpi-os
   ```

   ```
   df -h foo
   Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
   /dev/loop0p2    4.9G  4.4G  202M  96% /home/philip/rpi-os
   ```
2. [chroot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chroot) into the mounted file system

   ```
   sudo chroot rpi-os
   ```
3. Install any software you want, make any changes you want.  Eg:

   ```
   apt-get update
   apt-get install some-new-package
   ```
4. Exit and unmount

   ```
   df -h rpi-os
   Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
   /dev/loop0p2    4.9G  4.5G  149M  97% /home/philip/rpi-os
   ```

   ```
   exit
   sudo umount rpi-os
   ```

Comment: problem is a user cannot save anything, contents of partition will change and the checksum be different if anything is saved... for starters the `/tmp` folder would need to be a `tmpfs` file system.  If one is booting from an image file (just like a live cd) then when finished nothing would be saved... no browser bookmarks no text files.  When using an image file (or what you describe) it would or would have to boot that exact same each time for the partition checksum method to work... which is ok if the users are ok with it not needing any data created to be persistent.

Comment: @ron the way I read the question the OP doesn't need to run verification after use. If I understand the question correctly the organisers need to check the suppliers have delivered exactly what they were asked to before distributing to the users. As I've stated this isn't really possible if the suppliers are asked to modify the image.  You'll never know exactly what they did.  The rest of my answer is about ensuring the supplier has NOT tampered with the image before / after writing it to the SD. Here booting it might class as tampering.

Answer (score 0):

is there a way to check *Linux* installed a certain way, yes.

Disregarding legitimate updates and config file modifications...

- first maybe use LUKS to encrypt the linux root partition {would be an added defense but would present other complexities}
- first checksum all relevant files
- obviously the kernel typically located in /boot as *vmlinuz...something*
- corresponding initrd, initramfs, grub and efi files all under the /boot
- use AIDE in linux, which one linux is running is a database of checksums that will help *detect intrusion*
- write some script that will check basic stuff should be as expected: file system layout, folders mounted, services (chkconfig or systemctl) that are enabled/disabled

If everything checks out, then one can be somewhat certain everything's as it should be.  Problems arise with false alarms, for example u do a legit kernel update now the checksum needs to be changed to correspond to new kernel if not it will red flag it as changed.  And differentiating between .conf and other files that are important and what really matter versus those that can be changed which cause impacts that you don't or should not care about.

> How can I ensure that a provider isn't malevolent and attempt to add any other software we do not want to see on our SD cards ?

that's the million dollar question... how do you know {in no specific order} that ubuntu, suse, redhat/centos, debian, whoever the linux "provider" is did not slip something in?  Answer = choose a good provider.  Paranoia-ly speaking short of getting the "linux kernel source" then inspecting all that source to make sure "they" didn't slip something in... then inspect all 1000+ rpm's that go along with linux which make it work such as gnome and glibc to make something hasn't been slipped in... there's a risk.  To what extent u go to minimize that risk is up to you.  There's some 100+ linux providers, choose one that's been around and mostly vetted... like ubuntu, debian, suse, rh...

Comment: I'm not convinced by your likeness between a supplier and large scale open source distributions.  Open source is scruitenized massively by many people and peer reviewed before changes are pulled and published. Commercially a massive supplier like Asus or Microsoft has a massive amount to lose by foul play and a massive group of people trying to catch them out.  A small scale supplier from a foreign country providing 500 raspberry PIs is not subject to the same scruiteny and background checks. If they get caught they close and re-open as a new company name.

Answer (score -1):

Sticking to OP's question :

> Is there a way to check, if I take a SD card randomly and insert it in a Rasperry Pi, that the SD card has been created the way I expected, with the good commands ?

If you insert a card into a Raspberry Pi then boot it, I'm afraid you won't be able to check what's installed on it : the purpose of any rootkit is to hide its own existence.

Of course, the solution would be not to boot on it at all, and instead read / investigate / compare it from a system you own and you trust.

Comment: Why would the check need to be done after booting it, why not *before* it's been booted?

Comment: @PhilipCouling : edited my answer to better explain what I had in mind.